# IR data from Landis+Gyr E350

Tags: serial

I have purchased a ir->serial port cable for reading from the IR-port on electrical meters.

With the included program meter.exe, I can only get this:

```
C:\extra\Downloads\meter>meter -port=com3 
olcdtool version 1.00
Opening: com3, baud: 300
Meter ID: /LGZ4ZMF100AC.M29
```

then what looks like a question mark in a square.

But no data.

Any clues? Can the power company turn off the port so it sends no data?

EDIT:
The adapter is this: http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Optical-Probe-IEC1107-IEC61107-62056-21-with-USB-cable-Windows-10-version-/201922292332?

Here is the reader software: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qjhykezcojkt3g7/meter.zip?dl=0

EDIT:
I have now been told the question is off-topic.
As long as the question and answer stays here for reference, I'm okay with it being locked.

Comment: Where did you get that program _meter.exe_ from? Can you add some link to the product?

Comment: I got it with the cable; I can post it later.

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Comment: No, but now I added a link to the reader software. (on dropbox, but is available without login)

Comment: Look at the IR transmitter trough your phone camera and see if it lights up.

Comment: I can't. It's bidirectional; I have to send characters before it answers. And it answers, but only sends ID, not any data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get read from serial port to work, so I did this instead: cat /dev/ttyUSB0 to a file, and tail'ing until the end character "!"

```
#!/bin/bash
EYE=/dev/ireye             #ttyUSB number may change
find /dev -type f -delete  #remove real files in /dev
TMPFILE=`mktemp`
trap 'kill $CHILD; rm $TMPFILE' 0 #cleanup at exit
stty -F $EYE 300 cs7 parenb -parodd clocal -hupcl -opost -onlcr ignbrk ignpar -icrnl -isig -icanon -iexten -echo -echoe -echoctl -echoke

#send output from meter to tempfile
cat $EYE>$TMPFILE &
CHILD=$!
sleep 1
echo -n -e "\x2F\x3F\x21\x0D\x0A">$EYE
sleep 2
echo -n -e '\x06\x30\x30\x30\x0D\x0A'>$EYE
t=0
sleep 1
until tail $TMPFILE|grep "!" 
do
    sleep 1
    t=`expr $t + 1`
    echo -n "$t "
    if [ $t -gt 40 ] 
    then
        echo "Timeout"
        exit 1
    fi
done
# convert to json and send to mqtt
awk -f /root/j.awk $TMPFILE | mqtt-simple -h localhost -r -p smartmeter
kill $CHILD

echo "done $t polls"
```

Answer (score 1):

For this 300 baud 7E1 counter, you need to trigger the answer. Below example is on my Raspberry Pi system:

```
echo -n -e '\x2F\x3F\x21\x0D\x0A' > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

I think the above command is exactly what gives you your output ("LGZ4ZMF100AC.M29"). Then WITHIN 2 s max you need to send the next command:

```
echo -n -e '\x06\x30\x30\x30\x0D\x0A' > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

This should then trigger the answer from the device. In my case it gives me

```
F(00)
C.1.0(38294136)
0.0(70148674        )
C.1.1(        )
1.8.1(000093.853*kWh)
1.8.2(000004.012*kWh)
1.8.3(000004.013*kWh)
1.8.4(000004.013*kWh)
1.8.5(000004.014*kWh)
1.8.6(000004.014*kWh)
1.8.0(000113.919*kWh)
2.8.1(001870.106*kWh)
2.8.2(000000.000*kWh)
2.8.3(000000.000*kWh)
2.8.4(000000.000*kWh)
2.8.5(000000.000*kWh)
2.8.6(000000.000*kWh)
2.8.0(001870.106*kWh)
15.8.0(001984.028*kWh)
C.5.0(4401)
C.7.0(0009)
32.7(232*V)
52.7(231*V)
72.7(230*V)
```

Comment: Most interesting. I'll try this and report back.

Comment: @Transistor Which port did you put the "eye" on?
I have a port at the top and one in the middle on a GSM-module.

Comment: Did not work. Tried both ports :-(

Comment: It's not my answer, it's user165748. Write to him - I only fixed the formatting.

Comment: We talk about landis+gyr 350, correct? Mine looks like shown here https://www.landisgyr.de/product/landisgyr-e350-electricity-meter-new-generation/ I have no module installed and the only optical IR port is on the right handed front side of the device (see pic in linked description). My IR head has a magnet build in and you just plug it on the port, cable pointing down.

Comment: I have both an IR port at the top right and at the interface module in the middle.

http://www.dlms.com/images/lgz_e35_c.jpg

Comment: Ok so my description related to the port at the top right. Sorry cant help with the module port.

Comment: I'm missing the obvious, I think. After I echo, how do I read back?

Comment: Note: When debugging, be sure the reader is still attached. My "eye" have a weak magnet, so it have to be fixed to the meter with gaffertape :-(